# Performance of SCIP: how many variables and constraints SCIP can deal with, and how much time SCIP will take on solving?

Tags: scip

I'm new to SCIP, and I have a large-scale MINLP with about 500,000 integer variables, 500,000 linear constraints, and 100,000 nonlinear constraints.

I read a lot of papers about the performance of SCIP, but can't find how many variables and constraints SCIP can deal with.
One of the papers I found showing the number of sloved problems but not the number of variables and constraints as listed below.
https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs11081-018-9411-8.pdf

Is there any experience or paper I can refer to how many variables and constraints SCIP can deal with, and how much time SCIP will take on solving?

Answer (score 0):

There is hardly a limit on the size of the instances (if we're ignoring some limits imposed by the programming languages) that you can *pass* to SCIP - or any other MIP solver for that matter. Whether you can *solve* an instance in an acceptable time and without exceeding your memory is mainly a question of the computing resources at your disposal.

So, I'd say: Just give it a try!